# How to get the global coordinates of a 3D object inherited from a parent object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I'm developing with threejs, and I've created an object A and an object B, and I've made B dependent on A.
If you console B's worldmatrix, you'll see the worldmatrix value relative to the actual global 0,0,0.

```
console.log(B.matrixWorld)
```

**The results,**

**worldmatrix.element = [
0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
100, 0, 0, 0, 1]**
As you see, the world position is (100, 0, 0).
However, if I print elements to the console to get the position of B's worldmatrix, we get the following output

```
console.log(B.matrixWorld.element[12]) (position x) 
console.log(B.matrixWorld.element[13]) (position y) 
console.log(B.matrixWorld.element[14]) (position z)
```

As you see, the values in the local coordinate system of the B-matrix are output.
the result was 0, 0, 0. Why is it that when I print the worldmatrix to the console, I get the values in the global coordinate system just fine, but when I print the elements one by one, I get the values in the local coordinate system?